# DataFrame.apply with str.extract throws error even though function works on each column-series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

With this example DataFrame: `df = pd.DataFrame([['A-3', 'B-4'], ['C-box', 'D1-go']])`

Calling extract on individual columns as series works fine:

```
df.iloc[:, 0].str.extract('-(.+)')
df.iloc[:, 1].str.extract('-(.+)')
```

and also on the other axis:

```
df.iloc[0, :].str.extract('-(.+)')
df.iloc[1, :].str.extract('-(.+)')
```

So, I'd expect using apply would work (by applying extract to each column):

`df.apply(lambda s: s.str.extract('-(.+)'), axis=0)`

But it throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3325, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-588-70b1808d5457>", line 2, in <module>
    df.apply(lambda s: s.str.extract('-(.+)'))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 6487, in apply
    return op.get_result()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 151, in get_result
    return self.apply_standard()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 260, in apply_standard
    return self.wrap_results()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 308, in wrap_results
    return self.wrap_results_for_axis()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 340, in wrap_results_for_axis
    result = self.obj._constructor(data=results)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 392, in __init__
    mgr = init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 212, in init_dict
    return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 51, in arrays_to_mgr
    index = extract_index(arrays)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 308, in extract_index
    raise ValueError('If using all scalar values, you must pass'
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

Using `axis=1` yields an unexpected result, a Series with each row being a Series:

```
Out[2]: 
0             0
0  3
1  4
1         0
0  box
1   go
dtype: object
```

I'm using apply, because I think this would result in the fastest execution time, but open to other suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default parameter for expand in str.extract is True and it returns a Dataframe. Since you are applying it to multiple columns, it tries to return multiple dataframes. Set expand to False to handle that,

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.extract('-(.*)', expand = False))

    0   1
0   3   4
1   box go
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) instead.

```
df.apply(lambda s: s.str.split('-', expand=True)[1])

Out[1]: 
     0   1
0    3   4
1  box  go
```